# Build efficient SQL statements with multiple parameters in C#

Tags: c#, sql, list, foreach, ado.net

I have a list of items with different ids which represent a SQL table's PK values.
Is there any way to build an efficient and safe statement?

Since now I've always prepared a string representing the statement and build it as I traversed the list via a foreach loop.

Here's an example of what I'm doing:

```
string update = "UPDATE table SET column = 0 WHERE";

foreach (Line l in list)
{
  update += " id = " + l.Id + " OR";
}

// To remove last OR
update.Remove(update.Length - 3);

MySqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery("myConnectionString", update);
```

Which feels very unsafe and looks very ugly.

Is there a better way for this?

Comment: The resulting query would contain syntax error i.e. `UPDATE table SET column = 0 WHERE id = 1, id = 2, id = 3`

Comment: Hey, welcome to stack overflow, take a look here and see if this helps you out https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Comment: Generating dynamic SQL like this is open to SQL injection and generally not advisable. I'd look into parameterised SQL, e.g. `UPDATE table SET column = 0 WHERE id=@id`. It would be simpler to execute the same command multiple times than doing this in one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So yeah, in SQL you've got the 'IN' keyword which allows you to specify a set of values.

This should accomplish what you would like (syntax might be iffy, but the idea is there)

```
var ids = string.Join(',', list.Select(x => x.Id))

string update = $"UPDATE table SET column = 0 WHERE id IN ({ids})";

MySqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery("myConnectionString", update);
```

However, the way you're performing your SQL can be considered dangerous (you should be fine as this just looks like ids from a DB, who knows, better to be safe than sorry). Here you're passing parameters straight into your query string, which is a potential risk to SQL injection which is very dangerous. There are ways around this, and using the inbuilt .NET 'SqlCommand' object

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

Comment: You need `WHERE id` between `column = 0` and `IN (...)`. I'd also note that `ToList` isn't required (though isn't causing a problem).

Comment: would this have sql injection problem?

Comment: Yes, however it should be quite easy to get around that. Using the command param here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0  However I'm not quite sure if it allows the param to be an array, don't see why not though, been a while since I've used C#

Answer (score 0):

It would be more efficient to use **IN** operator:

```
string update = "UPDATE table SET column = 0 WHERE id IN (";

foreach (Line l in list)
{
    update += l.Id + ",";
}

// To remove last comma
update.Remove(update.Length - 1);

// To insert closing bracket
update += ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

If using .NET Core Framework, see the following [library](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/dyynamic-sql-where-in/tree/WPF-Bindingss/SqlCoreUtilityLibrary) which creates parameters for a WHERE IN. The library is a port from VB.NET which I wrote in Framework 4.7 years ago. Clone the repository, get `SqlCoreUtilityLibrary` project for creating statements.

**Setup**.

```
public void UpdateExample()
{
    var identifiers = new List<int>() { 1, 3,20, 2,  45 };
    var (actual, exposed) = DataOperations.UpdateExample(
        "UPDATE table SET column = 0 WHERE id IN", identifiers);

    Console.WriteLine(actual);
    Console.WriteLine(exposed);
}
```

Just enough code to create the parameterizing SQL statement. Note [ActualCommandText method](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/dyynamic-sql-where-in/blob/WPF-Bindingss/DbLibrary/LanguageExtensions/IDbExtensions.cs#L30) is included for development, not for production as it reveals actual values for parameters.

```
public static (string actual, string exposed) UpdateExample(string commandText, List<int> identifiers)
{

    using var cn = new SqlConnection() { ConnectionString = GetSqlConnection() };
    using var cmd = new SqlCommand() { Connection = cn };
    
    cmd.CommandText = SqlWhereInParamBuilder.BuildInClause(commandText + " ({0})", "p", identifiers);


    cmd.AddParamsToCommand("p", identifiers);

    return (cmd.CommandText, cmd.ActualCommandText());

}
```

> For a real app all code would be done in the method above rather than returning the two strings.

**Results**

```
UPDATE table SET column = 0 WHERE id IN (@p0,@p1,@p2,@p3,@p4)
UPDATE table SET column = 0 WHERE id IN (1,3,20,2,45)
```

Comment: would this have sql injection problem?

Comment: No as each value is parameterized.